# wget -k converts files differently on Windows and Linux

Tags: apache, wget

I've got **GNU Wget 1.10.2** for windows and linux and the **-k** option behaves differently on those two.

> -k,  --convert-links      make links in downloaded HTML point to local files.

On windows it produces:

```
www.example.com/index.html
www.example.com/index.html@page=about
www.example.com/index.html@page=contact
www.example.com/index.html@page=sitemap
```

and on linux it produces:

```
www.example.com/index.html
www.example.com/index.html?page=about
www.example.com/index.html?page=contact
www.example.com/index.html?page=sitemap
```

This is problematic in linux because when I serve the mirror through Apache it will not distinguish between the 4 generated pages since the part after the questionmark (**?**) character is used as the query string to the file.

Any ideas on how I can control this?

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use a question mark (?) in a filename on NTFS or FAT32. This is why wget uses the at symbol (@) instead.

In Linux, only a slash (/) is forbidden on most filesystems, so wget uses the question mark (since it's part of the URI).

You can force either behaviour by using `--restrict-file-names=unix` or `--restrict-file-names=windows`.

From the wget documentation:

> When mode is set to “unix”, Wget
>   escapes the character ‘/’ and the
>   control characters in the ranges 0–31
>   and 128–159. This is the default on
>   Unix-like OS'es.
>
> When mode is set to “windows”, Wget
>   escapes the characters ‘\’, ‘|’, ‘/’,
>   ‘:’, ‘?’, ‘"’, ‘*’, ‘<’, ‘>’, and the
>   control characters in the ranges 0–31
>   and 128–159. In addition to this, Wget
>   in Windows mode uses ‘+’ instead of
>   ‘:’ to separate host and port in local
>   file names, and uses ‘@’ instead of
>   ‘?’ to separate the query portion of
>   the file name from the rest.
>   Therefore, a URL that would be saved
>   as
>   ‘`www.xemacs.org:4300/search.pl?input=blah`’
>   in Unix mode would be saved as
>   ‘`www.xemacs.org+4300/search.pl@input=blah`’
>   in Windows mode. This mode is the
>   default on Windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot of the info. I could mass rename but I'd have to mass search/replace these references from the inside the html files themselves, right?

Comment: Yes, and that would be more work than necessary. It took me a moment but I found the command-line option. =)

Answer (score 4):

> This is problematic in linux because when I serve the mirror through Apache it will not distinguish between the 4 generated pages since the part after the questionmark (?) character is used as the query string to the file.

To include a question mark in a URL path part, you can escape it:

```
www.example.com/index.html%3Fpage=about
```

--convert-links should be doing this for you, I'd think — may be a bug if not.

Answer (score 3):

see [`--restrict-file-names=windows`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-Windows-file-names-60)

Answer (score 1):

> This is problematic in linux because when I serve the mirror through
>   Apache it will not distinguish between the 4 generated pages since the
>   part after the questionmark (?) character is used as the query string
>   to the file.

If it is already to late this sed command helped me:

```
find . -type f -name "*html*" -exec sed -i -r 's/(src|href)=(["\x27])(.*?)(\?)(.*?)\2/\1=\2\3%3F\5\2/g' {} +
```

It replaces ? in href= or src= tags with %3F. (\x27 is the single tick)